# Word Macro: AutoFitWindow table if it contains a specific string

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following code. My document have all tables, some table have diagrams, some tables have strings. If the table contain a cell that has a string "Black player", it would autofit that table to window fit, but it formats all the tables not just the tables that contain "Black player". Can someone help me please.

EDIT: I updated the code, and almost work. Is there a way to change Selection.Columns.AutoFit to something that can autofit to window not just Autofit? I appreaciate the help

```
Sub Find_Text_in_table()
    Dim tbl As Table
    For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        
        With Selection.Find
        .Text = "Black player"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With
        
                
        

        If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
            tbl.AutoFitBehavior _
            wdAutoFitWindow
            
        End If
        
        
    Next
    
End Sub
```

```
Sub Find_Text_in_table()
    Dim tbl As Table
    For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        
        Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = "Black player"
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With
        
        Selection.Find.Execute

        If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
                Selection.Columns.AutoFit
        End If

    Next
   
End Sub
```

Comment: The `Find` isn’t being executed and there is no connection between `Selection` and `tbl`, so all your code does is loop through the tables and set each one to fit to window.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
Selection.Find.Execute
If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
    Selection.Columns.AutoFit
End If
```

To:

```
If Selection.Find.Execute And _
    Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
        Selection.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitWindow
End If
```